# i want to access only date from datetime

Tags: apex, date

If i used `System.debug('date='+DATEVALUE(System.now()));` in developer console i am getting error msg by saying:

> method does not exist or incorrect signature for DATEVALUE(datetime)

How  i can do this.

i have custome object in that object senderdate field is available with datetime type.
suppose this filed data is

```
2013-08-02 00:20:00
2013-08-02 01:40:00
2013-08-02 00:20:00
2013-08-04 00:20:00
```

i want to access all row with same date i don't want time consideration.

```
i.e senderdate= 2013-08-02
it should display me 3 rows..
```

Comment: DATEVALUE is a Formula function, it can not be used in Apex, only in Visualforce, Custom Formula Fields, Validation Rules etc. You need to use the approach described in mast0r answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a `date()` method of the Datetime object:

```
System.debug('date=' + (System.now()).date());
```

Alternatively you can use `valueOf()` method of Date object:

```
System.debug('date=' + Date.valueOf(System.now()));
```

Is SOQL you can use a Date variables to compare a CreatedDate for example:

```
Date d = System.today();

List<account> a = [Select Id From Account Where CreatedDate = :d];
```

[Datetime Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm)

[Date Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm)

Comment: if i use System.now()).date() it is giving me date plus 00:00:00 for time.

Comment: @JayantJadhav Yes, this is a new Date object.

Comment: ya can i use date() function in soql. ex:

Comment: [select name from myobject where   datetimefile__c.date()=System.now().date()]

Comment: @JayantJadhav No, use just `TODAY` keyword http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

Comment: i will edit my question just have a look what is my requirement.

Comment: If you want to get a date string from a datetime just use e.g. system.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd'). This way you can control what the output looks like. Just mentioning this as your question involved debugging a string value of a datetime variable...

Comment: Actually, if you use `Date.valueOf`, it does not strip out time information, strangely enough. Try `system.debug(Date.valueOf(Datetime.now()))` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use

`System.debug('date=' + (System.now()).date().format());`

this will result 
2013-08-02 00:20:00 to 02-08-2013

Answer (score 3):

You can Use this

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,yyyy.MM.dd}">
   <apex:param value="{!MyVar.Holiday_Date__c}"/>
<apex:outputText>
```

Where ..... instead of **MyVar.Holiday_Date__C** use your DateTime variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Date.format` method which:

> "Converts the date to the local time zone and returns the converted
> date as a string using the supplied Java simple date format. If the
> time zone cannot be determined, GMT is used."

If you use `System.now()).date().format()` it will return something like `4/29/2021`